# Are distances in the depths smaller than on the overworld?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I have nothing to prove it but it does feel like distances in the depths, like between 2 lightroots, are smaller than if I was to walk between the 2 associated shrines on the overworld.

Is there a thing like the Nether in Minecraft, where distances in this underworld are a fraction of the overworld?

And if so, what is that fraction?

Comment: The map of the depths is the same size as the map of the surface, so if the depths is really smaller, the map would have to be scaled up to compensate. Your question is therefore equivalent to asking whether the map of the overworld is on the same scale as the map of the depths, and I can think of quite a few ways to measure that. For example, measure out a grid square and time how long it takes for Link to walk across it on both maps.

Comment: I suspect travel times could vary based on local topography.  If overworld traversal requires climbing over a cliff, then travel through the depths under that specific area may be faster.

Comment: There *are* fewer mountains below ground [citation needed].

Comment: @RavenDreamer: The depths have exactly the same topography as the surface, just upside-down (i.e. the depths have valleys where the surface has mountains and vice-versa). Bodies of water are replaced with walls.

Comment: Hunh, good to know.

Comment: @Kevin I hadn't noticed that.  That's clever!  And so obvious once pointed out.

Comment: @Batophobia Given the inverted nature of the terrain, one would expect that traversing both ways (A->B->A) negates the difference in surface layout between the over- and underworlds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tested this out, walking from Susuyai Shrine to Jiosin Shrine, and then from Iayusus Lightroot to Nisoij Lightroot. Both trips took the same amount of in time, 1 minute 40 seconds / 1 hour and 40 minutes in-game time. I don't believe the maps are at a different scale.